# I have a previuos easy HTML page with script linked to js files, for an AI test. How to link or to import to a wordpress site I'm testing on my own pc

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, import, include

Below the easy HTML code, taken from a tensorflow example. I have created on my own pc a wordpress site, just for test, and I would like to add the page or the contents of the page to the web site.  Two ways:
the first one, the preferred, try to integrate the HTML code and js file ( which mantain tensorflow commands, not related with themes) into a wordpress page. No problem for the HTML but I can not find the way to link the js file. I have tried modifying function.php, using wp_enqueue_script, but I don't understand where to store the js file according, and the path to specify. If it work in preview, it does'nt work when I public the page.  Also some other methods with no success. The second way is linking the old html page, but where I should insert the html file and the js file?

Thanks for your help, I'm really stuck.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
<script src="webcam.js"></script>
<script src="rps-dataset.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <video autoplay playsinline muted id="wc" width="224" height="224"></video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="0" onclick="handleButton(this)" >Rock</button>
    <button type="button" id="1" onclick="handleButton(this)" >Paper</button>
    <button type="button" id="2" onclick="handleButton(this)" >Scissors</button>
    <div id="rocksamples">Rock Samples:</div>
    <div id="papersamples">Paper Samples:</div>
    <div id="scissorssamples">Scissors Samples:</div>
    <button type="button" id="train" onclick="doTraining()" >Train Network</button>
    <div id="dummy">Once training is complete, click 'Start Predicting' to see predictions, and 'Stop Predicting' to end</div>
    <button type="button" id="startPredicting" onclick="startPredicting()" >Start Predicting</button>
    <button type="button" id="stopPredicting" onclick="stopPredicting()" >Stop Predicting</button>
    <div id="prediction"></div>
</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best approach would be to create a custom page template.

Are you using a custom theme or a theme from the wordpress theme repository?
I'm asking as the latter will frequently be updated and override customized option like those in your functions.php. In this case you might create a child theme.

See this description: [Create Child Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

You can then create a custom page template by creating a new file like
"page-tmpl-tensor.php" in your theme/child theme folder.

Its content is actually pretty close to your html code but it needs some wordpress specific funtions/variables to work

```
<?php 
/* 
   Template name: tensorflow 
   Template Post Type: post, page
*/ 
$theme_url = get_template_directory_uri();
?> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $theme_url; ?>/tensor.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
<script src="<?php echo $theme_url; ?>/webcam.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $theme_url; ?>/rps-dataset.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <video autoplay playsinline muted id="wc" width="224" height="224"></video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="0" onclick="handleButton(this)" >Rock</button>
    <button type="button" id="1" onclick="handleButton(this)" >Paper</button>
    <button type="button" id="2" onclick="handleButton(this)" >Scissors</button>
    <div id="rocksamples">Rock Samples:</div>
    <div id="papersamples">Paper Samples:</div>
    <div id="scissorssamples">Scissors Samples:</div>
    <button type="button" id="train" onclick="doTraining()" >Train Network</button>
    <div id="dummy">Once training is complete, click 'Start Predicting' to see predictions, and 'Stop Predicting' to end</div>
    <button type="button" id="startPredicting" onclick="startPredicting()" >Start Predicting</button>
    <button type="button" id="stopPredicting" onclick="stopPredicting()" >Stop Predicting</button>
    <div id="prediction"></div>
</body>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script src="<?php echo $theme_url; ?>/index.js"></script>
</html>
<!-- tensorflow -->
```

You can now create a new page in the wordpress admin area and should see your template "tensorflow" listed in the page template dropdown.

You might also replace the body content with thes lines to retrieve the content dynamically:

```
    <?php 
    setup_postdata($post->ID);  
    echo get_the_content(); 
    ?>
```

Now you could paste and edit your body html in the page's content field.
In this case make sure you paste the html in html/text mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help, all is very clear and tested until  creation of a new page and template tensorflow activation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. very clear for me till page creation, but because I'm quite new on Wordpress, is unclear where I should replace the body content with the code you suggest, and why I should copy again the HTML used to create the template as you suggest, at the beginning,  Thanks again

Comment: Have you been able to apply your custom template to your page? 
If you have successfully applied this template to a new page you should see at least the html comment <!-- tensorflow --> in your browser's source code output (firefox+chrome cnt + U).
If you see this output but your display is still messed up – then we're still missing some specific dependencies.
What theme are you using? If it's a regularly updated theme like the 'twenty X' or a theme available in the theme repository – you should  create a child theme.